# Improper integral that converges for all $x$ in $ \mathbb{R}$

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

> Let $f(x)$ be defined by the improper integral:
>   $$f(x)= \int_{0}^{\infty} \cos\left(\frac{t^3}{3} + \frac{x^2 t^2}{2} + xt\right)dt.$$ 
>   Show that this improper integral converges for all $x \in\mathbb{R}$.

How do you start this question? Do I evaluate the integral first, and then see if it satisfies all $x \in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What are the integration limits?

Comment: Either from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ or $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: The integral is defined for $-1<x<1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in\mathbb R$, then there exists an $N>0$ such that $t^2+x^2t+x>0$ for all $t>N$. Then, if $M>N$: you have that $$\int_N^M\cos\left(\frac{t^3}{3}+\frac{x^2t^2}{2}+xt\right)\,dt=\int_N^M\left(\sin\left(\frac{t^3}{3}+\frac{x^2t^2}{2}+xt\right)\right)'\frac{1}{t^2+x^2t+x}\,dt=\left[\sin\left(\frac{t^3}{3}+\frac{x^2t^2}{2}+xt\right)\frac{1}{t^2+x^2t+x}\right]_N^M+\int_N^M\sin\left(\frac{t^3}{3}+\frac{x^2t^2}{2}+xt\right)\frac{2t+x^2}{(t^2+x^2t+x)^2}\,dt.$$ The first term converges as $M\to\infty$, and the last integrand is bounded by $$\left|\frac{2t+x^2}{(t^2+x^2t+x)^2}\right|\leq \frac{ct}{t^4}=\frac{c}{t^3},$$ where $c$ is a positive constant, so it converges as $M\to\infty$.

Comment: What if $t^2+x^2 t+x=0$?

Comment: @RonGordon: you are right, I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the general idea would be to notice that for all $x$ you can find $A,s$ such that:
$$A t^2 < \frac{t^3}{3} + \frac{t^2 x^2}{2} + xt, \ \rm{when} \ t > s$$
Thus, the integral until $s$ converges, and the integral from $s$ oscillates faster than $t^2$, showing convergence.