# Terrible integral with parameter

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Let be   $\quad f(x)=\int_{0 }^{+\infty}cos\left(\frac{t^3}{3}+xt\right) d t$

Find the integral

$$F(x, y)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(t+x) f(t+y) d t$$

I tried exploring f(x), took it in parts, got that it converges. F(x,y) is difficult to investigate, since the product of integrals is there, I don't know what to do with it.

Comment: I'd suggest not to upvote this post as the OP hasn't mentioned his approach towards this problem. I request you Alex, edit your post to include *whatever* you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

You can noutice that $f(x)$ converges for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$

[Improper integral that converges for all $x$ in $ \mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/451972/improper-integral-that-converges-for-all-x-in-mathbbr)